# Existence of supremum implies existence of infimum

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, supremum-and-infimum

I'm reading *A Book of Set Theory* by Charles C. Pinter. I don't know how to solve exercise 4.3.11.

> Let $A$ be a partially ordered class. Prove the following:
>
> a) If every subclass of $A$ has a $\sup$ and an $\inf$ in $A$, then $A$ has a least element and a greatest element. [Hint: Use 4.27.]
>
> b) The following two statements are equivalent: Every subclass of $A$ has a $\sup$; every subclass of $A$ has an $\inf$.

Part a) seems straightforward: $A$ is a subclass of itself so $\sup A$ and $\inf A$ exist and must be its greatest and lowest elements respectively.

However I'm confused with b). Isn't it obviously false? Consider the partial order defined on the class $A=\{1,2,3\}$ represented in [this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dc33z.jpg) or equivalently given by the graph $G=\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,2),(3,3)\}$.

[image]

Then any subclass of $A$ has an infimum but $A$ itself does not have a supremum, right?

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this use of "subclass", but is $\{2,3\}$ a subclass of $A$?

Comment: Yes. You can replace every instance of "(-)class" by "(-)set" and the property still has to hold. This is because sets are classes (not necessarily the other way around). Whether it be sets or classes, I don't understand the exercise.

Comment: In your example, the empty set has no infimum. In fact, the infimum of the empty set is always the maximum of the whole set. (I'm arguing with sets, since I'm not familiar with these concepts for classes.)

Comment: You can prove the theorem by considering sups of lower sets or infs of upper sets, respectively. Again, just considering the "set case".

Comment: I see. The empty doesn't have an infimum for it should be the greatest of its lower bounds, i.e. the greatest element of $A$, which doesn't exist in my example. Out of curiosity, what do you mean by "set case"?

Comment: By "set case" I meant, just considering sets rather than classes. Although these ideas might work for classes as well.

Comment: This seems to be about totally ordered sets, but the same idea should work: [If an ordered set A has the least upper bound property, then it has the greatest lower bound property](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2858220) and [In Baby Rudin's Theorem 1.1, why is it important that $S$ has the least upper bound property?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2910182)

Answer (score 1):

In your example not every subclass of $A$ has an infimum. The set of lower bounds of the empty set is {$1,2,3$} and this does not have a greatest element.

To show part 2), suppose every subset of $A$ has a sup. Let $B$ be a subset of $A$. We will show $B$ has an inf by showing that the sup of the set of lower bounds of $B$ (which we know to exist by our assumption), $L(B)$, is the inf of $B$.

Suppose $B \ne \phi.$ Let $x=$ Sup $L(B)$ and suppose $y\in B$. Let $z\in L(B)$. Then we know $z\le y$ as $z$ is a lower bound for $B$. Hence $y$ is an upper bound for $L(B)$. By definition of Sup, we know $x \le y$, as $x$ is the least upper bound for $L(B)$. Hence as $y$ was arbitrary, $x$ is a lower bound for $B$. Now suppose $w \in L(B)$. Then $w \le x$ as $x$ is an upper bound of $L(B)$. Hence $x$ is the greatest lower bound of $B$.

If $B = \phi$ then we must show  $ \phi$ has an inf. Or the set of lower bounds of $ \phi$ has a greatest element. Or $A$ has a greatest element. But we know from our assumption that $A$ has a sup in $A$. Therefore $A$ has a greatest element.

The reverse direction follows a similar argument.